# Find area of shaded region in circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am working on this SAT question.

[image]

#### Progress

- AD = 3
- largest radius  =3
- second largest =  2

Comment: How far is it from A to D? What is the radius of the largest circle? Can you now figure out the various diameters given the information in the questin?

Comment: What work have you already done on this question? For example, have you figured out the distances $DE$, $CE$, $BE$, and $AE$? Have you figured out the radius of each circle? We are much more likely to help you if you show that you have done some work on the problem.

Comment: @HaraldHance-Olsen AD=3 radius larger =3

Comment: @DavidMitra  2= rad ssc.

Comment: AD = 3. So, ED = 3, EC = 4, EB = 5. Area of circle corresponding to EB = $\pi (\frac{5}{2})^2$. Area of circle corresponding to EC = $\pi (\frac{4}{2})^2$. Subtract area of the larger circle from the smaller and you should get $\frac{9}{4} \pi$

Comment: So, you see, it's not that hard to figure out. You could do it too, if instead of going straight for the answer, began to ask yourself questions of the form: What *can* I find out about the problem? Gather up a bunch of answer you can get at, then look to see if any of them lead to the answer to the original question. This is fundamental to the art of problem solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AB=BC=CD=1$  $\implies$  $AE=6$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ and  $\hspace{0.2cm}$$DE=3$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ because$\hspace{0.2cm}$$ D$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$is the center of largest circle.

Area of circle with diameter $CE=4$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ is $\hspace{0.2cm}$$\pi r^2=\pi 2^2=4\pi$

Area of circle with diameter  $BE=5$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ is $\hspace{0.2cm}$$\pi r^2=\pi (\frac{5}{2})^2=\frac{25}{4}\pi$

Hence the area of shaded region$=\frac{25}{4}\pi-4\pi=\frac{9\pi}{4}$